# how to map ERD where one of the relation is relationship between other entities?

Tags: database, relational-database, entity-relationship

[image: student database]

In this image, we can see there is a 1:M relationship between subject and relationship between student and class. I am not understanding how to map 1:M relationship. Can someone please help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Your diagram seems to indicate that a class is attended by only one student, and a subject is studied by only one student. Is that right?

Anyway, `Attends` will probably be implemented like so:

```
Attends (Student_ID PK/FK, Class_ID FK)
```

If it's really a one-to-one relationship then you can add a separate unique constraint on `Class_ID`.

`Studies` will be identified by the keys of its entity sets with plural cardinality indicators:

```
Studies (Subject_ID PK/FK, Student_ID FK)
```

or if it's actually a many-to-many relationship as I suspect:

```
Studies (Subject_ID PK/FK, Student_ID PK/FK)
```